# what is the difference between require and require

Tags: javascript, node.js, requirejs, amd, almond

What is the difference between these two with and without almond?

`require('module');`
`require(['module']);`

*Edit*

which are nested:

`define(function() { require('module'); }`

`define(function() { require(['module']); }`

former gives a requirejs error (that suggests to use the ladder).

The reason i am asking is,

I am studying
[example-libglobal](https://github.com/requirejs/example-libglobal) on
how to build a lib that can be used as an AMD module.

The library module we want to export:

`File: principium.js`

```
/**
* The main module that defines the public interface for principium,
*/
define(function (require) {
    convert = require('principium/convert');

    //Return the module value.
    return {
        convert: convert
    };
});
```

The main module that returns the library module.

`File: lib/main.js`

```
define(function() {
    //Use almond's special top-level, synchronous require to
    //get the final module value, and export it as the public
    //value.
    return require('principium');
});
```

In this example it uses almond to require `principium` (`return
require('principium')`), i expect that to return the exported library
object.

But i don't use almond, and `require('principium')` syntax gives
error, and if i use `require(['principium'])` instead, that doesn't
return the exported library object.

exported library object, That is i mean `return { convert: convert };`
returned in `principium.js`.

*Edit*

How can i use nested require properly so that:

`var moduleExport = require('module');`

works as i expect.

**Edit**

I solved it, but i don't know how it worked, I
included almond in the build and it worked magically.

`"include": ["../bower_components/almond/almond", "lib/main"]`

and refactored

`File: lib/main.js`

```
define([], function() {
    return require('principium');
});
```

Comment: You maybe want to remove your edit and answer your own question to mark as resolve :)

Comment: @apercu  I still don't know how it worked. Maybe someone can explain.

Answer (score -2):

It's "latter", because it's the later clause of two options, not ladder, which is a thing you climb up or down to reach otherwise impossible to reach elevations.

With that bit of "the more you know" out of the way: if you're using require.js, you cannot just require a module: require.js is for loading dependencies, in order to run a function, so the syntax is:

```
require(
  ['dependency1', 'dependency1',...],
  function codetorun(dep1, dep2) { ... }
);
```

your function is dependent on code from `dependency1`, etc, and therefore you "require" that code to be loaded and made available as variables to your function, before the function should even run.

Simply requiring in a module, without needing it for something, makes no sense as far as require.js can tell, so it throws an error.

Comment: can you read what i am trying to do, and solve my actual problem too.

Comment: wouldn't that be lovely? however, your actual problem isn't clear in the slightest because you've not described your file layout and your requireconfig. All of which is explained as necessary on the requirejs.org website, so... I answered the only question I could based on what you gave us to work with.

Comment: you don't have to write an answer if you can't understand the question, just to insult people.

Comment: that goes both ways. You asked about which format to use in your first few lines, so that's the part I can answer, because that's the part I understand. Anything else hopefully someone else can help you with - most SO questions have multiple answers and it's up to you to pick one if more than one answers your question. Or none, if none do. That's how stackoverflow works. Just don't award points if you aren't happy with an answer yet, simple as that.

Comment: see my edit sir, maybe that will help you. don't bother comment if not.

Comment: nope, based on your edit you're still asking about the difference between the two, and the difference is that the first is *wrong*, based on the require pattern require.js wants, and the second isn't, as per the explanation in this answer.

Comment: I think you are confused, the last example `main.js` makes use of `require('module')` and that's from the [example-libglobal](https://github.com/requirejs/example-libglobal/blob/master/tools/wrap.end#L13) from jrburke's repo.